# Swift 5 calling squareRoot()

Tags: swift, swift5

I'm reading through Swift 4 for Beginners. I'm making the a prime number checker and want to use the `squareRoot()` function to get the square root before division to check for a prime.

Heres my code:

```
 func isPrime(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
    switch number {
    case _ where number < 1 :
        return false
    case 1:
        return true
    default:
        break
    }
    let test = number.squareRoot()
    for i in 2..<number {
        if isDivisable(number, by: i) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
 }
```

The line `let test = number.squareRoot()` generates the compiler error

> Value of type 'Int' has no member 'squareRoot'

But if I replace the above line with:

```
test = 100.squareRoot()
```

Then there is no complier error. Both values `number` and obviously `100` are type `Int`. So what is the compiler not liking with my use of `squareRoot` on the parameter `number`

Hope this makes sense

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`squareRoot()` is a method defined in the [FloatingPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint) protocol, to which `Double` and `Float` conform, but not integer types like `Int`.

Therefore you have to convert the `Int` to `Double` (and the result back to `Int`):

```
let upperBound = Int(Double(number).squareRoot())
for i in 2..<upperBound {
```

The other example

```
let test = 100.squareRoot()
```

compiles because both `Int` and `Double` conform to the [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral) protocol, i.e. can be initialized from an integer literal. Here the compiler automatically infers `100` to be a floating point value because that is the only way to make the code compile. It becomes obvious here:

```
let test = 123.squareRoot()
print(test) // 11.090536506409418
```

Comment: that makes sense, ctrl clicking the 100 showed Int, but 100 can be inferred to type double . many thanks. Can I ask how you know this though. Is it experience or did you look at the protocol and method for squareRoot() ?

Comment: @hoboBob square root is not defined on integers, even in mathematics because the result cannot be expressed in integers. In programming it's a similar case. With enough experience you just know what to expect. In other programming languages the only difference is that integers can be automatically converted to a floating point number (without an explicit cast).

Comment: wow simples. ask a stupid question and get a really good answer. Thanks. I get Martins point with his edit too number is not a int literal its inferred as an Int.